# Overall, for the most part, which is more important--capturing prey or surviving predators or parasites?

Tags: genetics, evolution, zoology, immunology, food

For animals in nature, does selection intensity tend to be stronger upon abilities used against parasites or predators or abilities used against prey?  Any empirical reports would be appreciated.

I understand that it would depend somewhat upon the species and the time, but I'm asking about a typical generation in most species.

Comment: By strength of selection, I am assuming you mean what it typically means, that is the fitness variance in the population, right? Or do you mean something else like "number of deaths caused by ..."?

Comment: @Remi.b I mean that if you were to assign separate numerical values to  an individual's ability to capture prey and to an individual's ability to evade predators or parasites and you were to model that individual's fitness, would the coefficient in front of the ability to capture prey be higher or lower than the coefficient in front of the ability to evade predators or parasites?

Comment: The coefficients would depend upon the range of values your metric would take. But the fraction of variance explained by each trait is not. This is the definition I expected. It is likely hard to find such estimates but it is very interesting and it would great to have that. +1